# canvas is distorting itself and moving (fabric.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, fabricjs

I just need an advice on where to look at or where to start as right now I am confused. Not sure if this is CSS issue, javascript, or fabric.js

Problem:
 - I am adding a background image to canvas and sometimes it behaves really strange. And canvas is distorting itself sometimes on click, sometimes on resize, sometimes just without doing nothing. But this does not happen always.

These are two videos with the issue:

- https://jumpshare.com/v/4FU3xWjqk4h6j0OwqaFs (this is just without
     doing nothing).
- https://jumpshare.com/v/tBS7NJC5VgccWnIssETw (this is me clicking on canvas)

This is how I add an image to canvas (fetching url via API):

```
  $scope.openBlob = function($event, imageURL) {

            $rootScope.isLoading();
            $rootScope.centerSpinner();

            if ($rootScope.currentTab === 1) {
                var upload_thumb = angular.element($event.target.parentElement);
                var circular = angular.element('<md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" id="circular-images" md-diameter="30" ng-show="isAlsoLoading"></md-progress-circular>');
                $compile(circular)($scope);
                upload_thumb.prepend(circular);

            } else {
                var upload_thumb = angular.element($event.target.parentElement);
                var circular = angular.element('<md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" id="circular-new-middle" md-diameter="30" ng-show="isAlsoLoading"></md-progress-circular>');
                $compile(circular)($scope);
                upload_thumb.prepend(circular);
            }

            $rootScope.isAlsoLoading = true;

            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: imageURL.full,
                responseType: "blob"
            }).then(
                function(res) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(res.data);
                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                        canvas.loadMainImage(e.target.result);
                        $rootScope.started = true;
                        $rootScope.uploaded = true;
                        $rootScope.changeStyling();
                    };
                },
                function(res) {
                    console.log("For some reasons it failed to open", res);
                });

            if ($rootScope.currentTab === 1) {
                $rootScope.$on('editor.mainImage.loaded', function() {
                    $rootScope.isAlsoLoading = false;
                    upload_thumb.find("#circular-images").remove();
                    $rootScope.resetFilters();
                    $rootScope.isNotLoading();
                });
            } else {
                $rootScope.$on('editor.mainImage.loaded', function() {
                    $rootScope.isAlsoLoading = false;
                    upload_thumb.find("#circular-new-middle").remove();
                    $rootScope.resetFilters();
                    $rootScope.isNotLoading();
                });
            }
        }
```

LoadMainImage function content:

```
  loadMainImage: function(url, height, width, dontFit, callback) {
                var object;

                fabric.util.loadImage(url, function(img) {

                    //img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

                    object = new fabric.Image(img, canvas.imageStatic);
                    object.name = 'mainImage';

                    if (width && height) {
                        object.width = width;
                        object.height = height;
                    }

                    canvas.mainImage = object;

                    canvas.fabric.forEachObject(function(obj) {
                        console.log('image object', obj);
                        if (obj && obj.name == 'mainImage') {
                            canvas.fabric.remove(obj);
                        }
                    });

                    canvas.fabric.add(object);
                    object.top = -0.5;
                    object.left = -0.5;
                    object.moveTo(0);

                    canvas.fabric.setHeight(object.height);
                    canvas.fabric.setWidth(object.width);

                    canvas.original.height = object.height;
                    canvas.original.width = object.width;

                    $rootScope.canvaswidth = canvas.original.width;
                    $rootScope.canvasheight = canvas.original.height;

                    $rootScope.calculateImageType(canvas.original.width, canvas.original.height);

                    if ($rootScope.gridadded) {
                        $rootScope.removeGrid();
                        $rootScope.addGrid();
                    }

                    if (!dontFit) {
                        canvas.fitToScreen();
                    }

                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        $rootScope.$emit('editor.mainImage.loaded');
                    });

                    if (callback) {
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            },
```

Fit to screen function:

```
   $scope.fitToScreen = function () {
        $scope.zoom = canvas.currentZoom * 100;

        if (canvas.mainImage) {
            var oWidth = canvas.mainImage.width,
                oHeight = canvas.mainImage.height;
        } else {
            var oWidth = canvas.original.width,
                oHeight = canvas.original.height;
        }

        var maxScale = Math.min(3582 / oHeight, 5731 / oWidth) * 100,
            minScale = Math.min(141 / oHeight, 211 / oWidth) * 100;

        $scope.maxScale = Math.ceil(maxScale);
        $scope.minScale = Math.ceil(minScale);

        canvas.zoom(canvas.currentZoom);
    };
```

UPDATE: I am assuming that it might be scaling (zooming in and zooming out issue)

Comment: looks like a canvas resize problem. you should make a fiddle or a snippet here. How big are images and how big is canvas? what does fitToScreen does?

Comment: canvas is usually big. 3000x5000, 5000x5000, 7000x7000 something around like this always. added fit to screen to the question.

Comment: the strange distortion effect is caused by a small resize that cannot be handled very good by canvas. looks like you are resizing of 1 pixel.or similar.

Comment: Would you be able to pinpoint to a particular place in the provided code where I could have a look more? Or is this just a known fact for you and I should go through my whole codebase where I perform the resizes?